# Best way to implement "retries" when hitting api endpoint?

Tags: java, api, http, endpoint

I am using the **ApacheHttpClient**

I have a Java method (inside a Java microservice) that makes an Http **POST** request to an external endpoint (Endpoint that I do not own). Everything usually works well, but sometimes the endpoint is down and fails. The code looks something like this (simplified):

```
private HttpResponseData postRequest(String url) throws Exception {
        HttpResponseData response = null;
        try (InputStream key = MyAPICaller.class.getResourceAsStream(keyPath)) {
            MyAPICaller.initializeApiClient(Username, PassString, key);
            int attempts = REQUEST_RETRY_COUNT; // starts at 3

            while (attempts-- > 0) {
                try {
                    response = MyAPICaller.getInstance().post(url);
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Post Request to {} failed. Retries remaining {}", url, attempts);
                    Thread.sleep(REQUEST_RETRY_DELAY * 1000);
                }
            }

            if (response == null)
                throw new Exception("Post request retries exceeded. Unable to complete request.");

        }
        return response;
    }
```

I didn't write the original code, but as you can see, it looks like it makes a request, and while the *REQUEST_RETRY_COUNT* is greater than 0 (which it always will be it seems),  it will try to make a **post** to the url. It looks like for some reason there is a break point there, so after it jumps into the `try` block, it will always break out and there is no retry mechanism.

Is there a common design pattern in Java for implementing a Retry pattern for hitting an external endpoint? I Know in Javascript you can use the Fetch API with returns a promise, is there something similar with Java?

Comment: What sort of an API end point are you hitting, is it AWS, GCP etc?

Comment: Retrying is already part of `ApacheHttpClient`

Comment: The promise is JS represents a asyn operation, promise in itself doesn't retry on failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloud platforms like GCP and AWS usually come with their own retry strategy and that should be the preferred approach.

In case you want to role your own Retry strategy, exponential back off can be a good starting point.

It can be annotation based, where you annotate your client methods. For instance,
You annotate your API method as follows:

> @Retry(maxTries = 3, retryOnExceptions = {RpcException.class})
>   public UserInfo getUserInfo(String userId);

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Retry {

  int maxTries() default 0;

  /**
   * Attempt retry if one of the following exceptions is thrown.
   * @return array of applicable exceptions
   */
  Class<? extends Throwable> [] retryOnExceptions() default {Throwable.class};
}
```

The method interceptor can be implemented as follows:

```
public class RetryMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RetryMethodInterceptor.class.getName());

  @Override
  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocator) throws Throwable {
    Retry retryAnnotation = methodInvocator.getMethod().getAnnotation(Retry.class);
    Set<Class<? extends Throwable>> retriableExceptions =
        Sets.newHashSet(retryAnnotation.retryOnExceptions());

    String className = methodInvocator.getThis().getClass().getCanonicalName();
    String methodName = methodInvocator.getMethod().getName();

    int tryCount = 0;
    while (true) {
      try {
        return methodInvocator.proceed();
      } catch (Throwable ex) {
        tryCount++;
        boolean isExceptionInAllowedList = isRetriableException(retriableExceptions, ex.getClass());
        if (!isExceptionInAllowedList) {
          System.out.println(String.format(
              "Exception not in retry list for class: %s - method: %s - retry count: %s",
              className, methodName, tryCount));
          throw ex;
        } else if (isExceptionInAllowedList && tryCount > retryAnnotation.maxTries()) {
          System.out.println(String
                  .format(
                      "Exhausted retries, rethrowing exception for class: %s - method: %s - retry count: %s",
                      className, methodName, tryCount));
          throw ex;
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Retrying for class: %s - method: %s - retry count: %s",
            className, methodName, tryCount));
      }
    }
  }

  private boolean isRetriableException(Set<Class<? extends Throwable>> allowedExceptions,
      Class<? extends Throwable> caughtException) {
    for (Class<? extends Throwable> look : allowedExceptions) {
      // Only compare the class names we do not want to compare superclass so Class#isAssignableFrom
      // can't be used.
      if (caughtException.getCanonicalName().equalsIgnoreCase(look.getCanonicalName())) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with the code I already have, if you want to see.